# Why does the CSS @font-face rule only seem to work with some fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I went to the following site to check out some sweet custom fonts:

http://www.fontspace.com/category/ninja

If I try to use the "Last Ninja" font using the following CSS, it doesn't work (the font just looks like Times New Roman in my browser):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: LastNinja;
  src: url("/lastninja.ttf") format("truetype");
}

h1 {
  font-family: LastNinja;
}
```

But if I use the same code for the "Japonesa" font, it works:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Japonesa;
  src: url("/japonesa.ttf") format("truetype");
}

h1 {
  font-family: Japonesa;
}
```

I've tried this on both Chrome and Firefox. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It's really, really hard to find out what's going on without a demo (a link to the site if it's live, for instance?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried it and had same issue. The font seems corrupt or non-standard, even http://www.fontsquirrel.com rejects to convert the font.

Edit: [CodeAndMore](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/) service is able to convert this font (it converts to svg format only). [Preview](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/fonts/lastninja.html), [Download](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/fonts/lastninja1345828581.zip)

Edit 2: **Solution**
Convert the font from .ttf to .ttf with any [font converter](http://www.freefontconverter.com/) and use converted .ttf instead. This worked for me, tested in Chrome.